# The independence of friction on area of surfaces in contact

Tags: friction, laws-of-physics

Why is it said that **as long as the normal contact force remains the same or constant**, the frictional force is **independent** of the area of the surfaces in contact?

Does it mean when the normal force starts varying, the frictional force will **start depending** on the area of surfaces in contact?

I sound dumb but please clarify my doubt!

Comment: I guess the first sentence is only a (fairly good) approximation, but I'm sure it doesn't logically imply the second sentence

Comment: Contact mechanics (or Hertzian contact) as used in tribology explains this fairly well. The area of actual contact is smaller than the apparent area, and does relate directly to the normal force.

Answer (score 1):

As you note in your post, the frictional force is defined as being proportional to the normal force:$$\vec f=\mu \vec N.$$ So, of course when friction is defined in this way, there is no dependence on any measure of area and so varying the normal force only results in a corresponding variation in the frictional force, i.e. $\Delta \vec f= \mu\Delta\vec N$. This being said, in real life frictional forces do depend on area independently from the normal force, e.g. a wide rubber tire has more traction than a narrow one, hence the wide "racing slicks" used by race car drivers; such tires provide maximum surface contact with the asphalt.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is alluding to the notion of the normal forces depending on the area of the surfaces in contact, rather than direct dependence of the frictional force on surface area.

If you are standing on one foot, the normal force is equal and opposite your weight, and the maximum frictional force on your foot is $\mu mg$. If you instead stand on both feet and double the surface area, each foot now only supports half your weight and the maximum frictional force on each foot is only $\mu mg/2$.

The statement implies that if the normal force is independent of area, so too is the frictional force. But if the normal force depends on area, then so too does the frictional force.